# validation to accept alphabets and slash(/) in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a textbox, I want this textbox to accept alphabetical and forward slash (/) characters only.

How can I make it possible in a yii2 model?

```
 ['uri', 'match', 'pattern' => '^[a-zA-Z\s]*$']
```

I have used above in model. It is not working

Comment: Can you add examples of what strings this doesn't work on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule code instead of your rule.

```
['uri', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z\/]*$/' ]
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This One....

['uri', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z/\s]+$/']
```

Answer (score -2):

the regex should be something like and should work with yii:

```
preg_match('|[a-zA-Z/]*|', $string, $matches);  This is just a usage example of the regex for preg_match, of course the regex should work, not using preg_match in your case.
```